# I need help executing an remainder operator which by in use of if-function to console

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator, arithmetic-expressions, boolean-operations

```
var n = prompt('enter number');
let nint = parseInt(n)
let remainder = nint % 18
if (nint > 18){
      console.log( 'you can drive')
}else {
    nint < 18 && nint % 18
    console.log(`not yet ${remainder} years`)
    
}
```

if you are above 18 to print 'you can drive'
else less-than 18 to print 'you have to wait for ${remainder} of year to be 18 years above.
i have no idea to go ahead to the solution for my remainder. any one can help .

Comment: Why are you using remainder when you want to check for greater-than/less-than?

Comment: The remainder of a division is not going to be greater than the divisor.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say that, but *obviously* you need to substract one from the other.

```js
const n = prompt('enter number (representing your age)');
const nint = +n
const remaining = 18 - nint
if (nint > 18) {
  console.log('you can drive')
} else {
  console.log(`not yet allowed, you have to wait ${remaining} years`)
}
```